# ouput buffering confusing me!

Tags: plugin-development, proxy

I've coded a plugin that works with an external ReST API. It is possible to get a set of posts in JSON to render a post list in HTML. Now I want to extend it to provide download links for associated documents (in most cases pdf files). So much for the theory.

For another PHP CMS I've coded a proxy class. This class requests the API and gets the binary content of the documents. I'm using `ob_clean()` to clear the output buffer. I set a new header for `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...`, `Content-Type` and so on. In order to fetch the document I'm using curl. It works fine. But not in WordPress:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/sebastian/php_workspace/wordpress/wp-includes/admin-bar.php:792) in /Users/sebastian/php_workspace/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/bibsonomy-csl/lib/bibsonomy/CurlHttpRequestProxy.php on line 68
```

I've tried different ways to delete the output buffer, without any success. 
I tried:

```
while ( ob_get_level() ) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Also I tried to use PHP's `header_remove()` function. Nothing works.

How can I delete the output buffer in WordPress?

Comment: It is hard to follow what exactly you are doing. Output buffers in WP work exactly as usual (PHP, duh). But since plugins might be using them it's not trivial to reliably implement them at times.

Comment: I try to output pdf files.

Comment: Yes, I got the part about file output. But how exactly are you integrating that into WordPress?

Comment: I use the `the_content` filter.
`add_filter('the_content', 'download_document');`
In the download_document function I execute `ob_clean(); die();`. Nevertheless, a part of the html content of the page will be shown, instead of starting the download for the requested pdf file. When I start to output the binary content of the pdf, I get the 'headers already sent' message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_content()`, output of which you are filtering, is a template tag. It's meant to be used as part of HTML page. One page load cannot simultaneously be HTML page **and** PDF download.

File download you are generating needs to happen before HTML template is loaded, for example on `template_redirect` hook and `exit` after so that execution doesn't process to output HTML (or it would get stuffed inside your PDF file, likely breaking it).